# Make a form's background transparent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, background

How I make a background transparent on my form? Is it possible in C#?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can set the `BackColor` of your form to an uncommon color (say `Color.Magenta`) then set the form's `TransparencyKey` property to the same color. Then, set the `FormBorderStyle` to `None`.

Of course, that's just the quick and easy solution. The edges of controls are ugly, you have to keep changing the background color of new controls you add (if they're Buttons or something like that) and a whole host of other problems.

It really depends what you want to achieve. What is it? If you want to make a widget sort of thing, there are much better ways. If you need rounded corners or a custom background, there are much better ways. So please provide some more information if `TransparencyKey` isn't quite what you had in mind.

Comment: Dot Net 6.0 I get a big white form when I do that.  Is this only supported in the older frameworks?

Answer (score 17):

Put the following in the constructor of the form:

```
public Form1()
{
    this.TransparencyKey = Color.Turquoise;
    this.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
}
```

Note: This method prevents you from clicking through the form.

Comment: or better: TransparencyKey = BackColor;

Comment: or better: this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;

Comment: This approach makes the edges ugly. Especially when u have shadows.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**:

[How to: Give Your Control a Transparent Background](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Deprecated**:
[How to: Create Transparent Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czke9azk(v=vs.90).aspx):

> **Note**: As transparent forms are only supported in Windows 2000 or
>   later, Windows Forms will be
>   completely opaque when run on older
>   operating systems, such as Windows 98,
>   regardless of the value set for the
>   Opacity property.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to get a transparent background in a winform is to overwrite the OnPaintBackground method like this:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
//empty implementation
}
```

(Notice that the base.OnpaintBackground(e) is removed from the function)

Comment: But that just draws a completely black background…

Comment: This doesn't draw a completely black background. If you override this method and don't call the base class method nothing is drawn as a background. Three people (including myself) have tested this and it works for all of them.

Comment: This works, however any controls in the form that have Transparent set as their BackColor end up with the form's configured BackColor as their background. Would you have to override every control's OnPaintBackground event that you wanted to be transparent?

Comment: This suits me more because using this doesn't make the edges of the round controls ugly, also when using transparency key is messed up if you are using shadows on controls (at least thats what i've noticed)